# Offset splines with Animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

Before I am getting too deep into AN, I would like find out if there is ability to offset perpendiculary original spline by one of planes(xy, xz, yz), by using same control points? Is there also ability to control(translate, rotate, scale) particular control point in spline?

Comment: Never used Animation nodes so can't answer there, but Blender's curves have builtin *Offset* property in the *Object Data* options. It is limited though, and wont affect all features.

Answer (score 1):

You can offset the spline along whatever axis you want using the *Transform Spline* node, all control points are maintained.

[image: Offset]

To change the location of control points, use the *Spline Info* node to get the location of the control points, perform whatever transformation you want to do and create a spline from the result again using the *Spline From Points* node:

[image: Transform]

Comment: HI! That would not be what I need. This could describe http://what-when-how.com/computer-graphics-and-geometric-modeling/global-geometric-modeling-topics-part-7/